# Выбрать записи за текущий день отсортированные по просмотрам

Tags: sql, mysql

нужен пример с учетом h:m:s и какой тип поля использовать под дату?

Answer (score 1):

Преобразуйте к типу дата:

```
select now(), cast(now() as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ... from ... where date(datetime_field) = date(now())
```